# PHP Session and restricted mysql Access

Tags: php, mysql, security, session, cookies

I use a user management script with Sessions

the session object $loggedInUser contains these properties:

```
$loggedInUser->email
$loggedInUser->user_id 
$loggedInUser->hash_pw 
$loggedInUser->clean_username
```

the users are able to submit from *'form.php'* data through POST to
the processing script *'process.php*'

*'form.php'* has access to the before mentioned Session object.
This is the Cookie which is currently submitted at **sending** the form:

```
PHPSESSID=7ec81164c9fb2cdc4c6f47a00bc2ae50
```

**Question:**

How do I secure the *'process.php'* to savely allow only logged-in users to submit data?

*As far as i know, *'process.php'* is only accessed by my server and not the user, therefor i have to submit the Session Object either through Cookie, Get or Post which are all easy to tamper with, is that right?*

In which way, if appropriate, would you use the submitted Cookie or check the validation?

ATM its easy possible, knowing the path to the *'process.php'*, to "fake" a submit without logged-in Status.

Thank you for some words of wisdom :) from experienced programmers.

Comment: would it be advisable to send the form to PHP_SELF where i can wrap the INSERT into a conditional based on SESSIONS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `$loggedInUser` in session and check `$_SESSION['loggedInUser']->isLoggedIn()` (or however you normally determine if a user is logged in) in process.php.

Attackers can spoof the session_id, but not its contents. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation

Comment: However you probably shouldnt be storing the password hash in the session, only benign data like the username/userid.

Comment: But how is the Session Object available at the process.php? The user is not accessing this file with his browsers, the request is made from my server's file form.php. Do i understand something wrong here? i thought the only way to make the full SESSIONobject available is either through COOKIE,POST,GET or sending the form to itself !?

Comment: @Email You said the User submits form.php to process.php. I assumed you had a form with `action="process.php"`. Dump `$_SESSION` in process.php and find out for yourself.

Comment: @prodigitalson thx 4 the tip, i am just learning, your advise helps me alot.

Comment: @Mike yes that is correct. is it that process.php has access to the SESSION object (not Cookie/GET/POST sent) too?

Comment: @Email Every page requested by the browser should have access to the same session. The session identifier (PHPSESSID) is automatically passed via cookie or url (php takes care of this in case the user has cookies disabled).

Comment: @MIkE the $_SESSION, in my case $loggedInUser, does not contain anything, i used var_dump with ob_start ob_get_clean to write that to a file. I load the form via ajax after the Session has already been set at the wrapper script. Does that have an influence?

Comment: @Mike. Thank you. Now i understand after some testing. Your advise was right, i was not understanding the concept. thanks for the link too. always thought i can't trust session_id in cookie before.Searched for a way to do it without, now i see it is not necessary. HAVE A GREAT DAY and success in life :)